# Creating a boxplot from a binary variable using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- c(1,0,1,1,0)
qplot(data) + geom_bar() + labs(x="Merged", y="Count")
```

this generates:

[image]

However, I wanted to generate a boxplot, and have no use for the values 0.25, 0.50, and 0.75 since they cannot exist in this data. I simply want two bars for 0 and 1 indicating the count of each value in the dataset. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Looks like you mean barplot, rather than boxplot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- c(1,0,1,1,0)
qplot( as.factor(data) ) + 
    geom_bar() + 
    labs(x="Merged", y="Count")
```

This is based on @aosmith observation that a [factor](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/factor.html) will remove the ordinality of the data, and the @eipi10 observation that you're looking for a [barplot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html#), not a [boxplot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_boxplot.html#).

Yields
[image: boxplot]